# Multiple lines in RMAnnotation title in Mapbox?

Tags: ios, mapbox, smcalloutview, rmannotation

Im wondering if its possible to make the annotation title that comes up when you tap an annotation have multiple lines. Mapbox uses the SMCalloutView for that popup view.

The Mapbox references are very poor for ios...

Answer (score 0):

You can fork SMCallOutView an create your own custom version after you can Use it like this question.

[How to change margins in SMCalloutView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341610/how-to-change-margins-in-smcalloutview/28139595#28139595)

Comment: I ended up coming up with my own solution by creating a layer and adding it to the mapview.