# How to change margins in SMCalloutView

Tags: objective-c, mapbox, smcalloutview

I'm using Mapbox SDK and SMCalloutView

```
callout.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 115);
SMCalloutView *smcallout = [[SMCalloutView alloc] init];
smcallout.contentView = callout.view;
[smcallout presentCalloutFromRect:smcallout.frame inLayer:annotation.layer constrainedToLayer:map.layer animated:YES];
```

How can i change margins from contentView to borders of calloutView?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to build project using Mapbox and SMCalloutView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite the SMCalloutView as I did here:

https://github.com/Olinguito/YoIntervengoiOS/blob/master/Pods/SMCalloutView/SMCalloutView.m#L18

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the UIEdgeInsets of contentView.

```
[calloutView setContentViewInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

Comment: mmm... i tried to do that, but.. .how, because I have a var `SMCalloutView *currentCallout` but I tried to do `[currentCallout setContentViewInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];` or `[currentCallout.contentView setContentViewInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];` but doesn't work... what is wrong?